# Azure IoT Edge EFLOW behind proxy

Tags: azure-iot-edge

PC on which I have installed IoT Edge EFLOW is behind proxy.
I have tried to setup proxy as I did for standardalone Ubuntu instance i.a. by setting proxy for ubuntu (export https_proxy="...") and then setting proxy for docker.
Unfortunately I have noticed proxy settings are removed after each time host system has been restarted.
Futhermore I cannot modify docker configuration file via powershell and SSH connection.
When I try to open any file via nano or vim the powershell window is empty I cannot type anything, I can only exit by closing powershell window.

Is there any particular steps to do to start using EFLOW behind proxy?

Comment: Make sure you follow this: [Configure deployment manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-configure-proxy-support?view=iotedge-2020-11#configure-deployment-manifests) "Once your IoT Edge device is configured to work with your proxy server, you need to continue to declare the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable in future deployment manifests."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow this: [Configure deployment manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-configure-proxy-support?view=iotedge-2020-11#configure-deployment-manifests) "Once your IoT Edge device is configured to work with your proxy server, you need to continue to declare the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable in future deployment manifests."

Answer (score 0):

As part of our remote automation scripts, we've added the [EFLOW Autodeploy scripts](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge-eflow/tree/main/eflowautodeploy) that will let you deploy the EFLOW VM and all the configurations (**including Proxy**) just by declaring a JSON file.

Thanks,
Francisco